# Why are globular clusters always denser in the core?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, gravity, star-clusters

Stars falling towards the core speed up--thus, the amount of time they spend in any given volume goes down. Stars out near the edge move more slowly, thus their residence times in outer volumes should be higher. That would suggest that spherical collections of stars should have more mass on the periphery than in the core at any given time.

So... why do globular clusters in reality always have dense cores?

Comment: Are you assuming no energy transfer between objects?

Comment: It's for the same reason why star/planet has higher density at the core,- because there gravity force is stronger, i.e. mass always drifts/collapses to the COM.

Comment: Angius, no, not that trivial, because in stars/planets friction is important to dissipate angular momentum. Jon got it on the head, three-body interactions slowly cool the object, thus condensing it into its core. Logan: "more mass on the periphery" - do you mean higher density, or more mass integrated over the entire radial shell ;)

Comment: @rfl More mass integrated over the radial shell.

Comment: @JonCuster No. I am aware of processes like gravithermal collapse and binary heating, but that would seem to only explain why clusters eventually develop dense cores, not why they always *are*. Or is it in fact the case that young globular clusters *can* have more uniform densities?